# Using alt + print screen in remote desktop session produces strange wrapped image

Tags: remote-desktop

I've got a remote desktop session from my XP machine to a Windows Server 2008 machine.

With focus on a small window within the remote desktop session, I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and this is the result when I paste into Word, Outlook or Paint.NET:

[image: Print screen showing weird wrapped image]

Can anyone shed any light on how this might be fixed?  Doing the same on a local window works fine.  I know I can take the entire screen and crop it down but I'd prefer it just worked as it should.

Comment: I can't see a sample image in you text, maybe something went wrong here.

Comment: you are talking about the left border ?

Comment: @Revolter - yes, exactly that.  You can see the photo then :)

Comment: I too cant see the image, maybe a link to a image host?

Comment: Hopefully you can all see it now.  I have moved it to flickr.

Comment: I have the same problem when I paste to Photoshop, but not when I paste to mspaint, so pasting the image in paint, then copying from it, and then pasting in Photoshop is a workaround, but not the best solution. Did you get any solutions on this?

Comment: @David - I never found a solution to this.  In fact, I had the exact same issue again just today!  I usually just grab the entire screen (without the Alt modifier) rather than the specific window, and then crop it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of screen capturing you might benefit from using a dedicated screen capture software and maybe at the same time solve your problem. [Screenshot Captor](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/screenshotcator.html) is free and very good but there are plenty of free ones to choose from. Could be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I'll give it a go.  Still quite keen to understand why a basic piece of Windows functionality doesn't work though ... surely it's not just me?!